# Join between two tables duplicating some results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm joining two tables by this query in my PHP:

```
SELECT a.id,b.address
FROM mytable a 
LEFT JOIN mysecondtable b 
ON a.`id`=b.`id` 
WHERE a.`Name` LIKE '?'
```

And in the table b I have 2 lines with the same user 'id' but with the query I would like to have like:
for one id two address in the same result

For the moment I have 2 results looking like:

```
12 theaddress
12 thesecondaddress
```

And I would like

```
12 theaddress thesecondaddress
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Show us some more sample table data, and its expected result. (But I'd rather say you should re-design your tables...)

Comment: Perhaps GROUP_CONCAT? Hard to tell whether you're expecting columns, or strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use aggregation if you have at most two:

```
SELECT a.id MIN(b.address) as address1,
       NULLIF(MAX(b.address), MIN(b.address)) as address2
FROM mytable a LEFT JOIN
     mysecondtable b 
     ON a.`id`=b.`id` 
WHERE a.`Name` LIKE ?
GROUP BY a.id;
```

If you have an indeterminate number of addresses, you can put them into a string with a delimiter:

```
SELECT a.id GROUP_CONCAT(b.address SEPARATOR '|') as addresses
FROM mytable a LEFT JOIN
     mysecondtable b 
     ON a.`id`=b.`id` 
WHERE a.`Name` LIKE ?
GROUP BY a.id
```